# How to take the average mean of each year?

Tags: r, dplyr, group-by, tidyverse, mean

I have a data with contains measures of concentration of carbon and nitrogen from different years. It has many different measures for each year. I would like to obtain the average mean of C and N for each year, so I can plot the variation across the years.

I tried different functions that were recommended, but I can never make my code work..

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/HNOhP.png)

Comment: Reproducible example, please.

Answer (score 0):

You can use `dplyr`'s `summarise_all` function to do this. You can try something like this:

```
ad <- data.frame(year = rep(2009:2012, 15), C = sample(-100:100, 60), N = sample(-100:100, 60))

> head(ad)
  year   C   N
1 2009   0  49
2 2010  44  94
3 2011 -81 -84
4 2012 -43  55
5 2009 -64  14
6 2010 -62  31


library(tidyverse)
ad%>%group_by(year)%>%
  summarise_all(funs(mean))

# A tibble: 4 x 3
   year      C      N
  <int>  <dbl>  <dbl>
1  2009  -1.2  10.9  
2  2010   1     3.27 
3  2011  -1.87  0.667
4  2012 -11.1  -9.73
```

Answer (score 0):

If you are used to `sql`, then `sqldf` also does the trick.

```
sqldf("Select Year, AVG(C), AVG(N) FROM ad GROUP BY Year")
```